# codeigniter session data in two controller methods

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this two controller methods that both set session data

```
//Profile
public function profile()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('title', 'some_value');
}
//KYC
public function kyc()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('title', 'KYC');
    $this->load->view('basic/basic_app_views/kyc');
}
```

I am first loading the function `kyc` and using the session in my view

```
<title><?php echo $this->session->userdata('title'); ?></title>
```

I then load `profile` in my browser and refresh `kyc` but the value in `kyc` is still `KYC` like i had set in the kyc function.

How come `title` still has the value `KYC` even after resetting the value in another controller function?.

Comment: try to `unset($_SESSION['title'])`, before you set it the 2nd time

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I know i can unset as you say but its the why that i am interested in. Is the session variables unique to functions, that's the question.

Comment: You have no view in your profile method so you wont see anything. Every time you load kyc you are setting title to KYC and that will always show in the view you are using. In the code you have provided only the kyc shows anything and the title will always be KYC. So I am not sure of what you are expecting to happen? What view are you using for your Profile?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I am testing if session variables set in one function can modify existing data set by another function. So far, it appears that its not the case.

Comment: You can set that title session value in 100 different methods but each time you call/refresh kyc, title  will always be set to KYC which is exactly what the code is doing. What you would need to do is check if the title session is already set and if so ignore the one in the kyc method. Session variables are like any other with the exception they are "persistent". You test code is doing exactly what you have told it to do. Unless I am missing something I am not sure why you would expect it to be different.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thanks for the lengthy comment. I shall check it up and find out why its like so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the change in the session title variable you would need to change up your code a little...

So your

```
//Profile
public function profile()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('title', 'some_value');
}
//KYC
public function kyc()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('title', 'KYC');
    $this->load->view('basic/basic_app_views/kyc');
}
```

To something like...

```
//Profile
public function profile()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('title', 'some_value');
    $this->load->view('basic/basic_app_views/kyc');     // View the title value
}
//KYC
public function kyc()
{
    $this->session->set_userdata('title', 'KYC');
    $this->load->view('basic/basic_app_views/kyc');     // View the title value
}
```

That way you will see your value change. Each of your two methods individually change the value. But in your previous code only the kyc was displaying it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because each time you call your function it will set the userdata as it defines.

When try to set a title in a page, i suggest you to do this instead.

```
//Profile
public function profile()
{
    $data['title'] = 'Profile Page';
    $this->load->view('basic/basic_app_views/kyc', $data);
}
//KYC
public function kyc()
{
    $data['title'] = 'KYC Page';
    $this->load->view('basic/basic_app_views/kyc', $data);
}
```

then call it inside your `kyc.php` file.

```
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
```

hope that helps.

Comment: The OP was concerned about using sessions. In this usage case they are not the way to go. Your answer is the correct way to do it.